# setOnDateChangeListener is not working on lollipop

Tags: android

Code below works on API lower than lollipop but not on lollipop and newer version.

```
        date_picker.getCalendarView().setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            date.setText((month+1)+"/"+dayOfMonth+"/"+year);
            send_date = year+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+dayOfMonth;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Android 5.0.

It occurs when using the `DatePicker` in the material design calendar mode.

There are two workarounds i'm aware of:

1. Set the `android:datePickerMode` attribute of your `DatePicker` to `android:datePickerMode="spinner"` in your layout.
2. Use `DatePickerDialog` instead.